# Android DatePicker compatibility issue with MonkeyTalk library

Tags: android, datepicker, runtime-error, monkeytalk, android-runtime

I have implemented an Android app, and just added [MonkeyTalk](http://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk) library to test the usability of the system by recording user interaction with the app.

After using this library, everything works, but DatePicker!

I use the following method to show DatePicker dialog:

```
private void setSpecificDate() {

    int mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), 
            new OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {

                // part of code uses retrieved data from DataPicker...

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();
}
```

Then, as soon as I click to show the DatePicker, it crashes, I get the runtime error, and the program fails!

When I just comment out `dpd.show();` It works, but nothing happens.

I have also tested to use TimePicker instead of DatePicker to check app behavior, and it worked!

The runtime error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679): Process: com.parse.f8, PID: 2679
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679): java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at $Proxy6.onItemSelected(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:897)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:865)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.automators.AutomatorBase$MonkeyInvocationHandler.invoke(AutomatorBase.java:571)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    ... 12 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find field mOnDateChangedListener in any superclass of android.view.View$ListenerInfo
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.automators.AutomatorBase.chainListenerFor(AutomatorBase.java:483)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.automators.DatePickerAutomator.installDefaultListeners(DatePickerAutomator.java:43)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.FunctionalityAdder.processView(FunctionalityAdder.java:71)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.FunctionalityAdder.walkTree(FunctionalityAdder.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.FunctionalityAdder.walkTree(FunctionalityAdder.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.FunctionalityAdder.walkTree(FunctionalityAdder.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.FunctionalityAdder.walkTree(FunctionalityAdder.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.FunctionalityAdder.walkTree(FunctionalityAdder.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.FunctionalityAdder.walkTree(FunctionalityAdder.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.FunctionalityAdder.walkTree(FunctionalityAdder.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.aspects.OnCreate.ajc$afterReturning$com_gorillalogic_fonemonkey_aspects_OnCreate$7$35d40fb6(OnCreate.aj:115)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.parse.f8.view.SettingAdvTime.setSpecificDate(SettingAdvTime.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.parse.f8.view.SettingAdvTime.access$3(SettingAdvTime.java:373)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    at com.parse.f8.view.SettingAdvTime$1.onItemSelected(SettingAdvTime.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2679):    ... 16 more
```

I would appreciate anyone's assist to solve this problem.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue ? I came across a similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075930/my-date-picker-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment50172892_31075930

Comment: I did the same as you've done. Removed MonkeyTalk and created my own custom class to record the interaction logs in a remote server. I used Parse API for this purpose: https://www.parse.com